# Auth0 OAuth2.0 redirect 500

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

Is it ever expected to see a "500" status response during the final redirect from an OAuth2 provider?

```
server_error: Unable to issue redirect for OAuth 2.0 transaction
```

I'm trying to determine if this is ultimately the provider Auth0's error (it seems to be) or mine. If it were mine I'd expect a 400 series error. It is possible to have hooks or rules, could these result in 500-series errors in a scenario like this? I would also anticipate a more specific 500-error not 500 but another available number like 599 for lack of a better example.

My more specific case has something like:

```
new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: '....auth0.com'
            ,clientID: 'theid...'
            ,callbackUri: 'http://localhost:8080/'
            ,audience: 'http...',
            ,responseType: 'token id_token'
            ,scope: 'openid profile'
            ,leeway: 60
});
```

success then 500 for `/login/callback?state=...` on return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **misspelled the callback field,** it should be **`redirectUri`** (not callbackUri above)! Auth0 tech support was kind enough to point this out.

I also asked about changing the error from 500 internal server error to **400 "Bad Request" to indicate a missing client-provided detail** per my read of the details
https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml
details for 400 (and the rest) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1